Working vpn server on termux native with root?
Does anyone has a working way or a step by step guide to set-up a vpn server on termux with root? Like someone who actually tried and succeed or already has one running to give me tips and point me in the right direction.
This seems impossible and every single tutorial i found online is either outdated or missing things
Can we make a Vpn server run on Android?
Even this is a bit outdated, I tried the application he mentioned "servers ultimate" and it has never been updated since 4 years ago, It does work but you will never be able to connect to the server due to the "TLS HANDSHAKE ERRORS" I think this is because the application is using deprecated ways to generate the certificates or the 'SSL/TLS' Keys
is this impossible or just not worth it?

One very simple feasibility check would be using the Python tool mitmproxy. It provides a Wireguard mode. Just for testing if Wireguard VPN can be run as server on Termux this might be an easy test.

@Robert I tried it, Outdated and filled with issues. I think they forgot about it because seems like no one uses it and it's not very configurable.
